# Shifting object in partial array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to shift the objects in my partial array so that they get overridden, and everything gets shifted to the left. I know you can use an `arrayCopy` method, but I'm trying to use a `for` loop to understand what an `arrayCopy` method even means.
This was my first attempt:

```
boolean search = false;
for(int i = 0; i < (numCourses - 1 ); i++){
  if(arrayCourses[i].getRegistration() == crn){
   arrayCourses[i] = arrayCourses[1 + i];}
}
return search;
```

However, I realize that the `for` loop searched for the `crn` and then if it was equal to it, then it replaced it with the one greater than it and continued throughout the loop, so I still had the same number of courses at the end instead of replacing them.

So I made something else:

```
boolean search = false;
for(int i = 0; i < (numCourses - 1 ); i++){
  if(arrayCourses[i].getRegistration() == crn){
    for(int j = i -1; j > 0 ; j--){
       arrayCourses[j] = arrayCourses[1 + j];}
  }
 }
 return search;
```

So that it would search through the loop, start at the index and replace it with all the preceding objects in the array. But was I suppose to use a temporary variable to hold this instead? I guess my problem is understanding where the second loop should have started/ended.

Comment: Could you please post the array initialization and the wanted result so we can test ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. What is the purpose of the `search` variable?

Comment: @gknicker The search variable was to check if the crn to be replaced matched with the crn of any object in the array. If it did, return true. If not, return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static native void arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos,
                                    Object dest, int destPos,
                                    int length);
```

`java.lang.System.arrayCopy` is a `native` function in `java` so I doubt your loop will help you understand how it is "really" handled, as it is probably written in `c` and simply moves `pointer` to make it more efficient, but anyway.

Altough it is very unclear what your question is, or what you are actually trying to do, here a simple algorithm that will `shift` everything in an `array` to the left

```
public class Test {

    private Test() {
        final String[] arrayOfString = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

        for(final String s : shift(arrayOfString))
            System.out.println(s);
    }

    private String[] shift(final String[] pArrayOfString)
    {
        final String[] newArray = new String[pArrayOfString.length - 1];

        for(int i = 1; i <= newArray.length; i++)
            newArray[i - 1] = pArrayOfString[i];

        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

That will print `B,C,D`

Now adapt this code to whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, I think this will help guide me to what I want. The array was Course[] arrayCourses = new Course[12], and there was a main method that put objects into it. If this above method was called with a specific crn, then it was searched in the array of objects and replaced with the next object. In the end I was suppose to have replaced certain objects so that my arrayCourses had only 10 objects.